Script to automate process of duplicating multiple instances of a mesh, each one with a shape key applied

I need help to do a script able to automate the process of duplicating a mesh that has lot of shape keys, then applying as basis one of the shape keys or a combination of shape keys to the duplicated mesh and name it the same as the name of the applied shape key. I use blender 3.6.9 LTS.
the script shows the following commands as i do those actions
bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_elements":{'INCREMENT'}, "use_snap_project":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "use_snap_self":True, "use_snap_edit":True, "use_snap_nonedit":True, "use_snap_selectable":False, "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "view2d_edge_pan":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})   
# this command shows when i duplicated the mesh. Is it the same as [bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode='TRANSLATION')] ?

bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 76  
 # here i selected the shape with index number 76, which belows appears without the "Shape Key Lock" setting on the shape key panel as bpy.data.shape_keys["Key.017"].key_blocks["KK Mouth_default_cl"].value = 0.5


bpy.context.object.show_only_shape_key = False   
# False or True are both Good posibilities for applying the modified shape key, with the difference true will make to abolute value of 1.0, while false gives more control over the amount of shape key effect i need applied to the mesh as basis, for example for half closed eyes i would need this setting set to false and the shape key with a value of 0.5. This  appears when i do that
bpy.data.shape_keys["Key.017"].key_blocks["KK Mouth_default_cl"].value = 0.5

bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=True, apply_mix=True)
# I apply the selected shape key with the given value as basis to the mesh 

bpy.context.object.name = "7_-face eyes op|mouth default op.face"
# I name the mesh the same as the shape key applied to it. (which command is able to name the mesh the same as the applied shape key, better yet using wild cards if possible, that way tell the script to name all the duplicated meshes with "7_-face eyes op|mouth "PICK NAME FROM SHAPE KEY".face"

Given these commands, which ones should be present in a python script that is able to duplicate the mesh a given amount of times according to the given index shape key range, say from index 48 to 73, and applying the shape key to each of those copies. I tried doing a very basic script myself, but it doesn’t work the way i want, it only does it right with only one duplicated mesh. This script tries to duplicate the original mesh and apply a selected shape key to this duplicate, naming it and then reselecting the original mesh again to repeat the process but with another shape key.
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode=‘TRANSLATION’)
bpy.context.active_object
bpy.context.object.show_only_shape_key = False
bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 77
bpy.data.shape_keys[“Key.028”].key_blocks[“KK Mouth_default_op”].value = 1
bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=True, apply_mix=True)
bpy.context.object.name = “7_-face eyes op|mouth default op.face”

bpy.data.objects[“7_+face eyes op|mouth closed.body.001”].select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode=‘TRANSLATION’)
bpy.context.active_object
bpy.context.object.show_only_shape_key = False
bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 78
bpy.data.shape_keys[“Key.029”].key_blocks[“KK Mouth_smile_op”].value = 1
bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=True, apply_mix=True)
bpy.context.object.name = “7_-face eyes op|mouth smile op.face”

bpy.data.objects[“7_+face eyes op|mouth closed.body.001”].select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode=‘TRANSLATION’)
bpy.context.active_object
bpy.context.object.show_only_shape_key = False
bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 79
bpy.data.shape_keys[“Key.030”].key_blocks[“KK Mouth_smile_sharp_op”].value = 1
bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=True, apply_mix=True)
bpy.context.object.name = "“7_-face eyes op|mouth_smile_sharp_op.face”

-The following error appears
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\BAKED TEXTURES\CONVERTING2.blend\Text”, line 13, in
File “C:\BLENDER\blender-3.6.9-windows-x64\blender-3.6.9-windows-x64\3.6\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py”, line 113, in call
ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove.poll() failed, context is incorrect.
Thanks in advance for the valuable help and for your time.

Are you sure you want to use "shape_key_remove"? This doesn't seem to be something you want in your description.

Instead of the bpy module operations (bpy.ops.), I would use the bmesh module because the bpy.ops work with a context object that must be set up correctly and rely on Blender's UI. Many of the operators require that a specific UI area, window, and region is open (e.g. the 3D viewport or the UV editor) because they interact with and update the UI. This is also defined in the context object along with the active object and selected objects and all the other stuff.
If you call a bpy.op. operator you often need to overwrite the context. Have a look here A comprehensive list of operator overrides
If the context object is not properly initialized you get the
poll() failed, context incorrect? - Example: bpy.ops.view3d.background_image_add() and it is hard to figure out why it happens.
Here is a script that uses bpy.ops to deal with shape keys: Apply Modifier for Object with Shape Keys Add-on
bmesh and shape keys
With the bmesh module you can create a copy of the mesh, including all shape keys. Then you can mix the shapes. In the example, only one shape is selected (weight=1) and all others are removed from the copy.
The following script splits an object with shape keys into separate objects.
import bpy
import bmesh

# replacemnt for bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=True, apply_mix=True)
def remove_shape_keys_and_apply_mix(obj):
    key_names = [kb.name for kb in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks]
    
    for k in reversed(key_names):
        shape_key = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[k]
        if shape_key.value == 0.0:
            obj.shape_key_remove(shape_key)


def switch_to_shape_key(me, index):
    for i, kb in enumerate(me.shape_keys.key_blocks):
        kb.value = 1.0 if i == index else 0.0


def create_objects_from_shape_keys(obj):

    # Get the object's mesh
    me = obj.data
    
    # check for shape keys
    if me.shape_keys is None:
        print(f"Warning: object '{obj.name}' has no shape keys.")
        return False
    
    # loop through the shape keys
    for i, kb in enumerate(me.shape_keys.key_blocks):
        
        # filter the shape keys, e.g. process only 48 to 73 
        #if i not in range(48, 73+1):
        #    continue

        # activate nth shape key (#i)
        switch_to_shape_key(me, i)
        
        name_shape = kb.name        

        # create new object for the shape key
        me_shape = me.copy()
        me_shape.name = name_shape
        new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name_shape, me_shape)
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(new_obj)
        
        # remove all other copied and now unused shape keys
        remove_shape_keys_and_apply_mix(new_obj)
        
    return True

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = bpy.context.active_object    # get active object from context
    if obj:
        create_objects_from_shape_keys(obj)
    else:
        raise Exception('Object not set. Have you selected an object?')

Animated shape keys

Separated shapes

Related:

Copying shape key animations from one object to another (python)
Set active object with python


Thanks a lot @Blunder - Blunder. the script works wonders indeed. And to add a Filter Range Index filter of Shapes?

You're welcome. If you want to filter the shape keys you can do this in the # loop through the shape keys block and check if i is in the given range. The end index is not included so you need a +1. I've edited the answer and added an example filter code. Remove the # that is in front of the lines "if i not in range..." and the "continue" to activate it.

Thanks, a lot, you are awesome!!!
